# How to migrate a MySQL4 to MySQL5 database

Tags: database, linux, terminal, mysql

I have a database (db4) that was created by MySQL4, and a database (db5) that was created by MySQL5. db4 contains several tables with the charset latin1 and several indices, but no data that was encrypted using the MySQL "PASSWORD" function. db5 is empty.

I want to migrate all tables and indices from db4 to db5 (which are actually on the same server). Ideally this should be done without any loss of information and within a short period of time.

Which terminal commands do I need to download the complete database from MySQL4 and insert the data afterwards to db5? Do I have to re-create the indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be also done within a single step, using the following command:

```
 mysqldump -u dbo4 --password="..." --default-character-set="latin1" db4 | mysql -S /tmp/mysql5.sock -u dbo5 --password="..." --default-character-set="latin1" db5
```

Unfortunately the standard-values with special characters are not correctly imported, and there seems to be no way to avoid that: [How to maintain character-set of standard-values when uploading MySQL-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757158/how-to-maintain-character-set-of-standard-values-when-uploading-mysql-dump).

Answer (score 2):

You can make a dump of database in mysql4 using mysqldump. And than upload it to MySQL5 using mysql command.

```
mysqldump dbname > file
mysql dbname < file
```

All the indexes will be recreated automatically.

Comment: If the database is really huge, you could compress these files, eg with `mysqldump dbname | gzip > file.gz` then `gunzip -c file.gz | mysql dbname`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else needs to move a database from Mysql4 to Mysql5, here's what I did.

1. dump the database from the mysql4 server

   ```
   mysqldump -uuser -ppass db4 > db4.sql
   ```
2. fix some syntax problems ([source](http://matthiaslienau.de/blog/2013/6/21/converting-mysql4-database-dump-syntax-to-mysql5))

```sh
    # change comment style from -- to #
    sed -r -i -e 's/^--(.*)$/#\1/' db4.sql
    # change type declaration keyword from "TYPE" to "ENGINE"
    sed -i -e 's/) TYPE=/) ENGINE=/' db4.sql
    # adapt  timestamp field definition
    sed -i -e 's/timestamp(14) NOT NULL,$/timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,/' db4.sql
```

3. on the mysql5 server you can now import the modified SQL dump

   ```
   mysql -uuser -ppass db5 < db4.sql
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Sven, I think doing a backup of your data in db4 and restoring it in db5 will work for you.

**Backup**

```
mysqldump database_name > file_name.sql
```

**Restore**

```
mysql < file_name.sql
```