# How to maintain character-set of standard-values when uploading MySQL-dump

Tags: character-encoding, mysql

I have a MySQL4 database `db4` (charset: latin1) which I want to copy to a MySQL5 database (standard charset: utf-8) `db5` using the following command:

```
mysqldump -u dbo4 --password="..." --default-character-set="latin1" db4 | mysql -S /tmp/mysql5.sock -u dbo5 --password="..." --default-character-set="latin1" db5
```

The values of the entries are copied in a correct way. But the the german Umlaute (äüö...) which are contained in standard-values of some fields, are afterwards schown as "?"

What is wrong with my copy-command?

I simply want to keep everything as is was before (all data in the database stored as "latin1")

Comment: Try this: mysqldump -u dbo4 --password="..." --default-character-set="latin1" db4 | mysql -S /tmp/mysql5.sock -u dbo5 --password="..." --default-character-set="utf8" db5

Comment: I already tried that. That gives an error, `"ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 670: Invalid default value for 'data_with_umlaut'"`

Comment: Then remove the default value of the column. While exporting from 4x to 5x server there will be few compatibility issues. Are you getting this for auto-increment column?

Comment: No, auto-increment is OK. Its seem to be only the standard values with special characters. When I change theam afterwards in PHPMyAdmin, the charset is fine again. I have no idea whats wrong there. Would be great to know if I made the mistake, or if this is an error in MySQL,...